# Show $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\,f(u,t)dG(u)$ is a ch.f. where $G$ is a d.f. ; $f(u,\cdot)$ is a ch.f. and $f(\cdot,t)$ is continuous.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, characteristic-functions

> Show $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\,f(u,t)dG(u)$$ is a ch.f. where $G$ is a
>   d.f. ; and $f(u,\cdot)$ is a ch.f. for each $u$ and $f(\cdot,t)$is
>   continuous for each $t$.

Note that ch.f. means "characteristic function" and d.f. means "distribution function". It's a exercise from Kai Lai Chung's probability theory book.

My idea is that: in the special case $G$ is discrete, the problem is reduced to the following easy problem:

> If $f_n$ are ch.f.'s and $\alpha_n \ge 0$,
>   $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha_n=1$, then
>   $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\alpha_nf_n$$
>   is a ch.f.

I think the crucial point is how to use"$f(\cdot,t)$ is
 continuous for each $t$"

Comment: if you write out f(u,t) explicitly, the answer may be more assailable.

Comment: (To the OP and to @Conrado Costa) It is a good idea to quote the original wording of the problem: 


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn0OQ.png

Answer (score 1):

For each $u$ consider the random variable $X_u: \Omega_u\to \Bbb{R} $
here $\Omega_u= \Bbb{R}$ but we consider it endowed with the probability $\mu_u$ associated with the characteristic function $f(u,\cdot)$. The probability space is $(\Bbb{R}, \mathbb{B}, \mu_u)$

Extend  this to $(\mathbb{R}^{(-\infty,\infty)}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^{\otimes (-\infty,\infty)}, \mu^{\otimes (-\infty,\infty)})$ (use kolmogorov extension for intervals )

Now we have $\tilde{X}_u: \mathbb{R}^{(-\infty,\infty)} \to \Bbb{R}$ $\tilde{X}_u(\tilde{\omega}) = X_u(\tilde{\omega}(u))$with law given by $\mu_u$.
(notation $\tilde{\omega} \in \mathbb{R}^{(-\infty,\infty)}$, $\tilde{\omega}: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$)
 Let $Y$ be a random variable with density function given by $G$ and with law $\nu$

Extend one more time your space $(\mathbb{R}^{(-\infty,\infty)}\times \Bbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})^{\otimes (-\infty,\infty)}\otimes \Bbb{R}, \mu^{\otimes (-\infty,\infty)}\otimes \nu)$
(notation $\hat{\omega} \in \mathbb{R}^{(-\infty,\infty)}\otimes \Bbb{R}$, $\tilde{\omega}: \Bbb{R} \cup \{\Delta\} \to \Bbb{R}$)

$\hat{X}_u: \mathbb{R}^{(-\infty,\infty)}\times \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$
$\hat{X}_u(\hat{\omega}) = X_u(\tilde{\omega}(u))$ with law given by $\mu_u$.

$\hat{Y}: \mathbb{R}^{(-\infty,\infty)}\times \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$
$\hat{Y}(\hat{\omega}) = Y(\tilde{\omega}(\Delta))$ with law given by $\nu_u$.

Define $Z:\mathbb{R}^{(-\infty,\infty)}\times \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$ by $Z(\hat{\omega}) = X_{Y(\hat{\omega}(\Delta))}(\hat{\omega})$

Now we calculate

\begin{align*}
\Bbb{E}[e^{itZ}] &=  \int_{\Bbb{R}^{(-\infty,\infty)}\times \Bbb{R}} e^{it Z(\hat{\omega})}\, d\mu^{\otimes (-\infty,\infty)}\otimes \nu \\
&= \int_{\Bbb{R}}\int_{\Bbb{R}^{(-\infty,\infty)}} e^{it X_{Y(\hat{\omega}(\Delta))}(\hat{\omega})}\, d\mu^{\otimes (-\infty,\infty)}(\tilde{\omega}) \,d \nu(\hat{\omega}(\Delta))\\
&= \int_{\Bbb{R}} \Bbb{E}\bigg[ e^{it X_{Y(\hat{\omega}(\Delta))}(\hat{\omega})}\bigg]\, d\mu^{\otimes (-\infty,\infty)}(\tilde{\omega}) \,d \nu(\hat{\omega}(\Delta))\\
&= \int_{\Bbb{R}} f(\hat{\omega}(\Delta),t) \,d \nu(\hat{\omega}(\Delta))\\
&= \int_{\Bbb{R}} f(u,t) \,d G(u)\\
\end{align*}

which is a characteristic function.

**remark:** I didn't use continuity of $f(u,t)$. I'm not sure this is needed.